# How do I use web sharing in mac to allow access to files from machines outside of my local network?

Tags: ios, web-sharing

I want my web-service to be accessible from out side of my local network.

I am using MAMP and I have also started web-sharing on my local machine, but it is working only locally.

I want any file to be accessible from another machine which is not in network.

Comment: Are you looking at access to web pages or any file on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to try a dynamic DNS service (like DynDNS, http://dyn.com/dns/) to detect your machine's external (probably dynamic) IP address and keep it mapped to a specific DNS name.

The other option would be to get a shared hosting account and push your content up to a remote web server. I use A2hosting for that, but there are hundreds of similar hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

If the machines are on separate networks then you need to connect to the machine serving the files by it's external IP address. With this you should be able to connect to it using Finder by clicking *Connect to Server...* from the *Go* menu. If it is a Mac serving the files use:

```
afp://<IP-address>
```

and it should prompt you for a username and password.

Alternatively if it's just file access you desire and are not set on using a GUI, I recommend SSH and SCP: two command line tools.

SSH (Secure Shell) allows you to login to a remote machine and execute commands as if you were using a shell on that machine.

SCP (Secure Copy) allows you to securely transfer files between *NIX based machines using SSH protocols.

For information on how to use these, open a terminal and type either `man ssh` or `man scp`.